# Flash Shared Library items still add weight to my final swf

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, rsl

On one hand I have a shared library flash source file, that shares a movieclip with several icons inside. On the other hand I have the destination file that imports the shared library movieclip from the source file.

My problem is, I've tried both aproaches descibred in Adobe's documentation to import the shared library movieclip. You either edit the properties of an existing Movieclip and set check the option where it says "Import for runtime sharing", or you just drag the symbol from the source file library to the destination file library or stage.

The issues is, the only way I can get this to compile, is if I go with the second option. However, this way, all the icons inside that movieclip are also dragged into my destination file library, increasing it's final weight when I publish the swf file. So it just has no point at all in the end since I will be having the same bitmap files with the same weight in all files that import this movieclip.

Has anyone come across this issue before? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you use a bitmap, jpg, video or any other data in your swf, the filesize of the data will be included in the swf.  A bitmap is a bitmap, there's no magic compression.  You can publish your swf without the bitmap and load at runtime (when user requests).

Comment: Thats what I want to do, I want it to load those resources at runtime. But they are included in my library when I drag the symbol from the source file. If I just set the import on an empty movieclip for instance, I get a compilation error.

Comment: I'm following the instructions given here: http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/using/sharing-library-assets-across-files.html

Comment: You use Loader.  Here's a good tutorial for loader:  http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3loader/